# Sort strings numerically after non-numeric

Tags: javascript, sorting

I want to sort numerical data after non-numeric.  For example this is the correct order: `ab,ax,a1,a2,a10,bb,b3,b10`

I tried,

```
list.sort(function(a,b) { return a.localeCompare(b, 'en', {numeric:true });});
```

but it returns: `a1,a2,a10,ab,ax,b3,b10,bb`

**NOTE** i'll post one answer, but I'll accept a different one if it is better.

**EDIT** : to clarify, I need a lexical order in which the digits are *after* the non-digits, but otherwise the order is the usual a,b,c...  So 'bb' is sorted after 'a10'.

Comment: What is the exact order you expect? You do not show it in your question.

Comment: @epascarello Thanks, i will fix it

Answer (score 0):

The simplest (but not very efficient) solution is to insert 'zz' before each number in the string before comparing it.

```
function prep(a) { return a.replace(/(\D)(\d)/g,'$1zz$2'); }

var list=['a1','a10','ab','ax','a2'];

list.sort(function(a,b) {
    return prep(a).localeCompare(prep(b),'en', {numeric:true });
});
```

Comment: and when a string contains zz? ;)

Comment: @epascarello Ah, you're right! i should have used `'zzz'`. ;) I tried to find a unicode character that would sort after any other character. Some people suggested using omega Ω

Answer (score 0):

Split the string from the number and do the comparisons by themselves.

```js
var strs = ['ab','ax','a1','a2','a10', 'ab2', 'ab1']

strs.sort( (a,b) => {
  let aParts = a.match(/(\D*)?(\d+)?/)
  let bParts = b.match(/(\D*)?(\d+)?/)
  if (aParts[1] === bParts[1]) {
    return (+aParts[2] > +bParts[2]) ? 1 : -1
  } else if ((aParts[1] && !aParts[2]) || (bParts[1] && !bParts[2])) {
    return !bParts[2] ? 1 : -1
  } else {
    return aParts[1].localeCompare(bParts[1], 'en')
  }
})

console.log(strs)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `reduce` to split numeric and non-numeric data into two arrays. Then we sort them individually and use `concat` to combine them.

```
list
.reduce((acc, item, index) => {
  let i = +/\d/g.test(item);
  acc[i] ? acc[i].push(item) : acc[i] = [item];
 return acc;
}, []),

result = list[0].sort().concat(
  list[1].sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, "en", {numeric: true})
));
```

```js
let list = ['a10', 'ab', 'aa', 'a1', 'a2', 'ax']
.reduce((acc, item, index) => {
  let i = +/\d/g.test(item);
  acc[i] ? acc[i].push(item) : acc[i] = [item];
 return acc;
}, []),

result = list[0].sort().concat(
  list[1].sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, "en", {numeric: true})
));

console.log(result);
```